# Insert new data inside ElasticSearch with tornado-es library

Tags: asynchronous, elasticsearch, tornado

I'm using asynchronous "tornado-es" library for Tornado and I'd like to know if is there a way to insert new data inside an index.

Is it possible to perform this operation? If this is the case, how can I perform it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to look through the source code of "tornado-es" library but I didn't find how to perform this.

Comment: use `put` function for this https://github.com/globocom/tornado-es/blob/master/tornadoes/__init__.py#L78

Comment: Hi @kwarunek, thanks for your comment.
I tried to use `put` function, but it also requires `uid` as parameter and I don't have any information to insert for that.

Is it possible to insert new data in a way where ES automatically generates `uid` info? Something like the `index` function of `elasticsearch` library for Python.

Comment: Follow here. In the process of being updated to be as similar to the elasticsearch-py library, as possible. https://github.com/debosmit/tornado-elasticsearch :)

Comment: Hi @Debosmit Ray,

thank you very much for your hint, I'll take a look to the library :)